# Backbone handle array of strings

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Using Backbone.js I need to handle an array of strings returned from a JSON web service. Should I create a Backbone Collection to fetch this list? Here is the data I get from the web service:

`["Question Designer","Adaptive Question Designer","Clickable image map","Essay","Fill in the blanks","Maple-graded","Matching","Mathematical formula","Multipart question","Multiple choice","Multiple selection","Numeric","Palette-based symbolic editor","True/false","Other"]`

I've created this simple Collection to fetch the data:

```
var questionTypesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function() {
    return apiBase + '/questions/types';
  }
});
```

But when I try to fetch() the collection, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in Question Designer
```

It looks like Backbone is trying to parse the strings as a model instead of seeing that it's just a raw string. How can I get the data into a Collection so I can use it in a View?

Comment: Collections ARE collections of Models.  There's no concept of a Collection of anything other then Models in Backbone.

Comment: I understand that. The question is how should I fetch an array of strings using Backbone? It's easy using jQuery.ajax, but I want to be consistent about how I interact with the web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the strings, your best bet might be to just let jQuery (or Zepto--whatever has the `$`) handle the heavy lifting:

```
var names = [];

$.get(apiBase + '/questions/types', {}, function(result){
  names = result;
})
```

After the fetch completes, the `names` variable will be populated with the results of your query.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make a lot of sense, since backbone collection is designed to be, well, a collection of models.
However, you could override the [`parse`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-parse) method with your own parser.